# Do all local site moderators have access to everyone's email address

Tags: discussion, moderation

Do all local site moderators have access to everyone's email address? I'm not especially worried, as I'm not a troll, but wondered if there was room for abuse, and whether moderators have any contract (extra moral) about not emailing or sharing email addresses with anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from us having to explicitly agree to an agreement that is legally binding and forbids the access to and use of PII if not absolutely necessary for moderation matters, you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/who-can-see-what-in-my-profile) in an answer from a Staff Member that while we have access in principle, it is a deliberate act of clicking needed and this is system-logged to prevent abuse.

Generally, Meta.SE is the place where you can almost certainly find all answers on general site mechanics. I just used "email address moderators" in the search line and this post (to be exact, a duplicate linking to it) was the first hit.

Comment: In addition, we also have a mod-only help page about private communication with users that explicitly says not to email users except with explicit permission, and adds, "If you just want to connect with a user on a personal level, please don't use the information you have access to in your official capacity as moderator."